# Laptop HDMI to DVI monitor not working "no signal"

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, dvi

I have a laptop (dell inspiron 7537) with an hdmi output and I would like to connect it to a monitor (Samsung PPM42S3Q ) which has only VGA and DVI input. 
I bought a dvi to hdmi adapter (hdmi female dvi male) but when I connec laptop to monitor I always get “no signal” that means cable is connected but no signal is sent or recognised by monitor.

First, I suppose cable wasn’t working, so I connect my laptop to another monitor (more modern than the samsung) with the same configuration and everything works like a charm.
After I figure out that cable was working I connect my PC Desktop to the Samsung monitor with the same configuration and everything is working.
I supposed was a graphic card issue, my laptop has and intel integrated graphic card and a Nvidia Geforce Gt 750M , I tried to enable one and disable the other and viceversa but in the end I got always the same result “no signal”.

Could anyone please suggest another configuration or tell me if is possible to get this configuration working?

Comment: That should be a valid configuration, have you played with the resolution on when plugged into the monitor, sometimes the monitor will report no signal if the resolution is not supported by the monitor.

Comment: yep, I did it.. nothing happened

Comment: next I would check to see if you have the correct dvi connector. You may have a case where you are trying to send a digital signal to a analog monitor or vice versa. [Here](http://www.wsgf.org/f/u/Dvi_types.png) is an image if the differences in dvi as well as there pin counts

Comment: sorry mate I forgot to write dvi detail.. they are both dvi D (Monitor and adapter)

Comment: That is odd, just to make sure, is your laptop detecting the monitor and just not outputting to it?

Comment: no laptop doesn't detect the monitor, but when cable is not connected monitor displays "cable not connected", when is plugged in it displays "no signal"

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old question... An addittional avenue would be that the laptop video signal output is an incompatible resolution or refresh rate for the target monitor. There will also be EDID and HDCP to factor in, too. Personally I'd immediately start with trying to force the HDMI resolution (through the laptop OS) to a low resolution (e.g. 1024x768) and see if an image displays on the monitor.

Comment: @Kinnectus thanks for your support. I am not able to try because I throw that old monitor :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connecting HDMI output to DVI input is not straightforward due to HDMI carrying an [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection)-protected signal.

Monitors that don't have an HDMI port are not HDCP-compliant, hence can't display an HDCP-protected digital signal.

As a (legal) workaround you can try an HDMI splitter, those often strip HDCP from the signal, so it can be subsequently converted to DVI.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I already tried with an HDMI splitter and even with that it doesn't work. Maybe my problem depends on the hold DVI monitor.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer!** I've experimented with this, and it seems that HDMI to DVI cables just don't work properly with laptops. *However,* using a **regular DVI cable with an HDMI adapter** at the laptop end **does work**.

I would guess that there could be truth that there is an issue with HDCP not being translated, that seems most likely.
I originally had one of those cheap plastic block adapter things, but it's too wide and blocks the USB port next to the HDMI port - so I'm buying an adapter with 20cm or so cable attached, like this: https://www.scan.co.uk/images/products/super/2283293-l-a.jpg

Comment: I have a DVI adapter with an HDMI cable.  Works on a raspberry pi but not on a lenovo laptop!

Answer (score 2):

So based on the comments to the question, I think we have narrowed it down the the HDMI to DVI adapter. The monitor is not detecting a signal from the computer because the computer is not detecting that there is a monitor plugged in. Im not an electrical expert but when a VGA or DVI cable is plugged in at both ends it appears to complete a circuit, resulting in the display showing that the cable is plugged in. In this case this is why the monitor is showing `no signal` but is detecting a cable plugged in. The `no signal` is representing the fact that there is no data being sent between the monitor and the computer. For reasons unknown the monitor doesn't seem to like the adapter.

**What I Would Suggest**:

1. If you are able to get a different adapter I would try that first, it may just be an issue with the brand of adapter you are using.
2. Possibly try a different conversion, if you are able to adapt to VGA, see if you can get your hands on a HDMI to VGA
3. Look into a converter rather then an adapter. An adapter, the way I understand just adapts the plug to the needed port where as a converter actually converts the signal as well as the port.

Comment: I tried a new cable Hdmi to DVI but nothing has changed!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an Dell U2311H monitor. HDMI only is not working but surprisingly it worked when I linked the monitor with an extra USB cable to use the USB ports of the monitor as USB hub for the keyboard and mouse

Answer (score 0):

I have a Toshiba P50 with VGA and HDMI outputs.  I have two HPE241i monitors (which will do 1920x1200) as well as the P50 display (which will do 1920x1080).

The HP monitors don't have HDMI inputs, only VGA, DP, and DVI-D.

The P50 drives the VGA input at 1920x1200 on HP monitor 1 and the DVI input at 1920x1200 on HP monitor 2 via a $10 passive HDMI to DVI adaptor, which as far as I am aware does nothing more than pin reassignment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue between my laptop (Predator Helios 3000) and an old monitor (LG FLATRON E260T-PN) with only DVI-D and VGA ports. I was using an HDMI with a DVI to HDMI adapter on the monitor. It said "no signal". Tried a bunch of stuff but what seems to have worked in the end was simply flipping the HDMI cable...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).