# HDMI -> DVI not working on M1 Mac

Tags: mac, display, hdmi, dvi

I'm trying to use an HDMI -> DVI cable with an M1 Mac mini and a display with DVI. The Mac can see that the display is connected but the screen stays black.

I've tried:

- Using the same cable with an older Mac with HDMI out. That works, so the cable seems good and the display works with this conversion.
- Using a different HDMI display with the M1 Mac with a plain HDMI cable. That works, so the Mac's HDMI port seems good.

This is the cable: https://www.startech.com/en-us/cables/hddvimm3

This is the display: https://www.sharpnecdisplays.us/products/displays/ea232wmi-bk-r

A couple of possibilities I've found that haven't helped:

- [Another post](https://superuser.com/questions/1106034/laptop-hdmi-to-dvi-monitor-not-working-no-signal) suggested that the problem has to do with HDCP. For what it's worth the display's manual says it supports "DVI (HDCP)".
- Other sources mentioned DVI-A vs. DVI-D being a problem. The display's manual clarifies that it's DVI-D, so I think I'm OK there.

Does anyone have other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There's always the chance Apple just wants you to buy their own branded HDMI-DVI adapter, considering they specifically list that product on the official specs page: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP823?locale=en_US

Comment: First, congrats on the M1 Mac mini.  I'm loving mine, hope you are too!  I'm using an HDMI-to-DVI adapter (probably the Apple one, although I don't see their logo on it), a generic DVI cable, and a Panasonic monitor.  It works most of the time, but sometimes on wake from sleep or restarts there's no video out.  Happens like once a week, though, not that often.  See if you can buy Apple's adapter somewhere where you could also return it, if it doesn't help.

Comment: Is there another HDMI display (HDTV?) you can try hooking the M1 Mac Mini to, to cross test?  I wonder if it could be that the M1 is currently outputting an HDMI resolution that is not compatible with the NEC display.  Just guessing at possibilities here...

Comment: @Blaelph Yes, that's what I meant about using a different display with a plain HDMI cable. It's works fine, but that monitor can't be used with this Mac on a daily basis. Also for what it's worth, the mini detects the NEC display and reports the correct resolution (checked by using screen sharing).

Comment: According to a lot of Apple-related blogs, Big Sur 11.2 fixed an HDMI-to-DVI issue on the Mac mini.  I can't find a link to the Apple Release Notes, but a lot of sites are quoting it in the their initial 11.2 write-ups.  Haven't upgraded myself yet, but you might want to have a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in macOS 11.1. The release notes for 11.2 read, in part

> macOS Big Sur 11.2 improves Bluetooth reliability and fixes the following issues:

> •   External displays may show a black screen when connected to a Mac mini (M1, 2020) using an HDMI to DVI converter

I upgraded to 11.2 and it works.

Comment: Oh my, I almost checkout the Thunderbolt to HDMI before I found your solutions and try it. Now I can see mac boot screen after VNC for update the OS.